# Interactive shell in Deno

Tags: deno

In python, the following line results in an interactive shell which I can use like any terminal.

```
os.system("bash");
```

Typing exit here quits the shell and the python script continues to execute.

How can i do something like this in Deno?

Edit: I should have been a bit more verbose in my initial question. My intent is not just to run a shell command. I want to run an interactive shell which grabs input/output until I manually exit with exit command.
Deno.run({cmd: ["bash"]}) does not do this.

Comment: There is [Deno.run()](https://deno.land/manual/examples/subprocess) function to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run an arbitrary shell command from Deno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142699/how-do-i-run-an-arbitrary-shell-command-from-deno)

Comment: Edited the question to add more details - Deno.run does not result in a shell that is interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the process (the bash shell) to exit. To do this, you to need await [`process.status()`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.Process).

```js
// run using 
// deno run --allow-run demo.js

const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["bash"],
})

const status = await p.status()
console.log(status)
```

If you want to do it the Deno REPL, then run-

```js
await Deno.run({ cmd: ["bash"] }).status()
```